# WatchService.take() does not wait on Windows-7-x64, while watching changes in the remote directory

Tags: java, directory, windows-7-x64, watchservice

I am trying to watch the remote directory (on the network machine) using WatchService available in Java SE 7. It works just fine when I run the program on Windows XP, but on Windows 7 the WatchService.take() doesn't wait, returning an invalid key.

Here is the sample code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent.Kind;

public class MyWatchingService {

public void watchDir(Path path) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    try (WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {

        path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);        

        while (true) {
            // gets a watch key
            final WatchKey key = watchService.take();

            // retrieves pending events for a key.
            for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : key.pollEvents()) {

                // retrieves the event type and count.
                // gets the kind of event (create, delete) 
                final Kind<?> kind = watchEvent.kind();

                // handles OVERFLOW event
                if (kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW) {
                    continue;
                } 

                final WatchEvent<Path> watchEventPath = cast(watchEvent);
                final Path entry = watchEventPath.context();

                // outputs an event type and entry
                System.out.println(kind + " -> " + entry);
            }

            boolean valid = key.reset();

            //exit loop if the key is not valid
            if (!valid) {
                System.out.println("Key is invalid!");
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}

public void writeFile (Path path, String fileName) throws IOException {
    Path target = Paths.get(path.toString(), fileName);
    if (target.toFile().exists()) {
        Files.delete(target);
        System.out.println("file is deleted ok!");
    }
    Path fileTo = Files.createFile(target);
    Files.write(fileTo, String.valueOf(true).getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
    System.out.println("file is written ok!");
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
    return (WatchEvent<T>)event;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // case 1: network directory mapped to Y volume
    final Path path = Paths.get("Y:/workspace");
    // case 2: local directory: 
//  final Path path = Paths.get("D:/workspace");

    MyWatchingService service = new MyWatchingService();
    try {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        service.watchDir(path);
        System.out.println("exiting after " + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms...");
        service.writeFile(path, "test");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Key is invalid!
exiting after 16ms...
file is deleted ok!
file is written ok!
```

As you can see, I checked whether I can write/delete file in this network directory. I also tried without mapping defining a path like this: `//server/workspace` with no luck either. If I ran the same program for the commented out case 2 with local directory, then it goes into waiting with no output as expected.

I use jdk1.7.0_17, 64 bit. (I tried jre7, 32 bit, but no luck either). The remote directory is located on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

I read in the API the following sentence which make me suspicious that it is not possible at all:

> If a watched file is not located on a local storage device then it is
>   implementation specific if changes to the file can be detected. In
>   particular, it is not required that changes to files carried out on
>   remote systems be detected.

It will be bad news for me as I invested a plenty of time in this strategy using WatchService. Does someone have any ideas/experience why it doesn't work on Windows 7, or is it at all possible? And if not, what would be an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

As the docs say: I wouldn't expect 'watching' to work on a network drive *at all*.

If it does work or not certainly depends on the OS of the client and maybe its configuration *and* on the OS of the server and maybe its configuration, plus some other, unknown factors; seems extremely fragile and not worth counting on.

A simple alternative is mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html), too:

> [...] or to use a primitive mechanism, such as polling, when a native facility is not available

The polling approach can be implemented in pure Java without using `NIO` at all. Warning: Heavy resource-usage (network) may be the result.

And, as always, be advised to step back a little and re-consider if you really need to build your 'network protocol' upon those file-system operations, or if you can achieve what you want/need in another way.